# SQL Search - Strange Behaviour getting date of max value

Tags: sql, mariadb

So I'm running a query against a MariaDB in PHPMyAdmin, its been working fine until we have got to a new month and for the life of me I can't see the issue. The table is in the following format as an example, it contains data for both July and August so far:

| timestamp | generation | export |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-08-01 23:00:00 | 43.4 | 12.5 |

The SQL that's working for for returning the MAX value for month 7 and year 2023;

```
$sql_a = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`timestamp`, '%a %d %M') AS timestamp, `generation` FROM solar_generation WHERE `generation` = (SELECT MAX(`generation`) FROM solar_generation) AND MONTH(timestamp)= 7 AND YEAR(timestamp) = 2023";
```

This outputs exactly what I expect:

```
Fri 07 July 43.0
```

If I change the SQL to month number 8

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`timestamp`, '%a %d %M') AS timestamp, `generation` FROM solar_generation WHERE `generation` = (SELECT MAX(`generation`) FROM solar_generation) AND MONTH(timestamp)= 8 AND YEAR(timestamp) = 2023;
```

I get the following despite there been data in the table;

```
MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows)
```

If run the following query:

```
SELECT MAX(`generation`) FROM solar_generation WHERE MONTH(timestamp)= 8 AND YEAR(timestamp) = 2023;
```

I get the MAX generation as I'd expect for August, as soon as I start building the query for getting the data it stops returning data?

What is it I'm doing wrong, I just assumed the same query would work or is there a flaw in the query that is exposed by month 8 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer provided by [Littlefoot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76851485/sql-search-strange-behaviour-getting-date-of-max-value#76851857) shows exactly where the problem is.

The max value doesn't belong to the August month.

You need to make a little change to your logic . Find the max value per specific month and year.

In your case it would be ,

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`timestamp`, '%a %d %M') AS timestamp,
      `generation` 
FROM solar_generation
WHERE `generation` = (SELECT MAX(`generation`) 
                      FROM solar_generation where MONTH(timestamp)= 8 
                      AND YEAR(timestamp) = 2023
                     );
```

I suggest using with clause at is more performant and easily to adapt if future changes happen,

```
with max_val_per_month as (
  select `timestamp`,
          `generation` ,
         row_number() over(partition by MONTH(timestamp),YEAR(timestamp) order by generation desc ) max_gen
  from solar_generation
  ) select  DATE_FORMAT(`timestamp`, '%a %d %M') AS timestamp,
            `generation` 
    from max_val_per_month
    where max_gen = 1 
    and  MONTH(timestamp) = 8
    and year(timestamp) = 2023
```

See [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/06X660ct)

Comment: Perfect thanks, works a dream. I can't apply 2x Ticks but you both deserve some credit for this, explained well and clearly a logic issue !

Answer (score 2):

I don't use MariaDB.

However, this looks suspicious:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`timestamp`, '%a %d %M') AS timestamp, `generation` 
FROM solar_generation 
WHERE `generation` = (SELECT MAX(`generation`) FROM solar_generation)     --> this
  AND MONTH(timestamp)= 8 
  AND YEAR(timestamp) = 2023;
```

Basically, it says:

- query table named `solar_generation`
- find all rows in that table whose `generation` column value is equal to the **largest** `generation` value in the **whole table**

  - that's most probably only one row that satisfies that condition, although there can be more of them that share the same (max!) `generation` column value
- then, among all these rows (only one? A few of them?) fetch only those whose month is August (and year 2023)

  - apparently, as you didn't get any result, the largest `generation` value doesn't belong to August (2023)

This is Oracle, but disregard that fact; it is just to illustrate what I think is going on:

```
SQL> select * from solar_generation;

TIMESTAMP  GENERATION
---------- ----------
13.07.2023         20
28.07.2023         99  --> this is MAX generation; July 2023
14.08.2023         50
24.08.2023         80

SQL> select max(generation) from solar_generation;

MAX(GENERATION)
---------------
             99   --> OK, that's it
```

Now, let's select all rows that satisfy conditions: max generation and July:

```
SQL> select * from solar_generation
  2  where generation = (select max(generation) from solar_generation) --> this is 99
  3    and extract(month from timestamp) = 7;

TIMESTAMP  GENERATION
---------- ----------
28.07.2023         99
```

What about max generation and August?

```
SQL> select * from solar_generation
  2  where generation = (select max(generation) from solar_generation) --> this is 99
  3    and extract(month from timestamp) = 8;

no rows selected

SQL>
```

Right; there are no rows because `generation = 99` belongs to July.

---

I don't know what result you expect as you didn't explain it; if it is about max generation *per month*, then you'd do something like this (Oracle again; adjust it to MariaDB syntax):

```
SQL> select to_char(timestamp, 'mm.yyyy') month,
  2    max(generation) max_generation
  3  from solar_generation
  4  group by to_char(timestamp, 'mm.yyyy');

MONTH   MAX_GENERATION
------- --------------
08.2023             80
07.2023             99

SQL>
```

Comment: Not an Oracle person but I can see the issue explained this way - Thanks 'Littlefoot'